# Calculating abv with fruit on secondary

Tags: alcohol-content

So I am brewing with fruit and just added 6 pounds of apricots in syrup to a 7 gallon batch.

I am trying to understand how the abv will be affected since fermentation just kicked off again vigorously.

Is there a way to calculate the abv?

Comment: I was going to answer "no", because all fruits are different in sugar content, but then I thought of this test. Get maybe 1 liter of clean water (SG=1.000, obviously). Measure, say, 100 g of apricots. Pulverize them in a blender to the ultimate degree. Add to the water. Run through a filter to get enough solution for measuring SG. Measure SG. That's your maximum sugar; in the real setup there will be less sugar added to beer. All that left is doing some math.

Comment: you can calculate it, since this sounds like a processed fruit, then added to syrup.......if you have the nutritional information you may be able to get total sugars added if you added the syrup too.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can easily. When using juice/syrup/slurry.

But you need precise gravity and volume readings.
Just average the gravity of mixed solution based on syrup volume addition.

For example if the wort is 4 gallons of 1.050 OG, and the syrup is 1 gallon of 1.100 SG.
1.050 (wort gravity)x4 (4g wort volume) =4.2 + 1.1 (1g syrup at 1.1sg) = 5.3 / 5 (total volume)
Blended OG is 1.060

Even if the wort is fermented out when the syrup is added this math holds true for final ABV calcs. Using the calculated OG and an actual FG.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, similar in concept, is to determine the sugar content and reference a table. If you are using a puree or other product with a label, check the sugar content and convert into grams per liter or ounces per gallon. Then you can check a chart like [this one](http://www.brsquared.org/wine/CalcInfo/HydSugAl.htm) to get the gravity addition.

For example, this [blackberry puree](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0064OLUQE) has 12 grams per serving and 10 servings in the container. Ignoring the volume of the puree itself (for simplicity, and most will be left behind), that means we are adding 120 grams or 4.2 oz. If this is a 5 gallon batch, we are adding 4.2oz/5 to get oz/gallon, which is going to be roughly 2.5 gravity points.